# Windows 10 VPN Issues

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I have created a VPN using Windows 10's Wizard and using Checkpoint Capsule VPN.

I've put the credentials, and they are accepted by the VPN. But when I try to navigate to a URL that should be accessible via VPN, it simply won't load. In the Network screen, it shows 2 networks: Ethernet, which is my usual connection, and my VPN, which says "No Network Access". I made sure to remove the "Default gateway" on both IPv6 and IPv4 on the VPN. Still, it won't work. I can navigate to google and such, but it all seems to be going through the Ethernet.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect properly- You can check if Automatic config is turned on. Go in Start -> Settings -> Network & Internet -> VPN -> now pick your VPN connection and click on Advanced Options button. Find "Automatic configuration" and turn it on... and disable all next settings (like use script or manual configuration) if u have some.

If that didn't work, maybe you have some custom configuration on Ethernet- turn all to default - and check again :)

And last idea from me is- try "Troubleshoot problems" (right mouse click) from tray network icon.

Good luck!